# HAProxy. Traffic balancing based on AD groups

Tags: haproxy

I have backend app servers with LDAP authentication.
Is it possible to configure balancing based on AD groups ?

For example
ADUser1(ADgroup1) -> HAProxy -> backend servers1
ADUser2(ADgroup2) -> HAProxy -> backend servers2

The user-to-group mapping is hard, one-to-one only.